# Zoned timestamp format conversion in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, date, format

My file has data like below

```
a,b,d,f,e,2014-09-16T01:57:48.295Z,2017-07-13T02:01:03.059Z
s,d,fe,r,t,2014-09-17T01:57:48.295Z,2017-07-23T02:01:03.059Z
wa,db,td,yf,de,2013-09-26T01:57:48.295Z,2017-07-13T02:01:03.059Z
aws,dedr,tgyfe,juir,ttt,2018-09-17T01:57:48.295Z,2017-07-23T02:01:03.059Z
```

In the timestamp fields, replace 'T' with blank space, and remove 'Z' part.

I used to received json file with huge data. Need only some columns in .csv format. I could able to extract the fields in .csv format. But couldn't able to proceed with date format conversion.

```
# load json in panda dataframe
# parses through the json (normalize)
# filter required columns and write into .csv file
# remove the index field (first column) 


def conversion():
    data_set = pd.read_json("/a/b/c.json")
    normalized_data = json_normalize(data_set['data'])
    new_data=pd.DataFrame(normalized_data['data'].values.tolist())
    filtered_data = new_data[["f1","f2","f3","f4","f5","date1","date2"]]
    filtered_data.to_csv("/a/b/c/file1.csv",index=False)

conversion()
```

expected output is

```
a,b,d,f,e,2014-09-16 01:57:48,2017-07-13 02:01:03
s,d,fe,r,t,2014-09-17 01:57:48,2017-07-23 02:01:03 
wa,db,td,yf,de,2013-09-26 01:57:48,2017-07-13 02:01:03 
aws,dedr,tgyfe,juir,ttt,2018-09-17 01:57:48,2017-07-23 02:01:03
```

Answer (score 0):

convert values to `datetime64[s]`

```py
df['date1'] = df['date1'].astype('datetime64[s]')
df['date2'] = df['date2'].astype('datetime64[s]')
```

```py
    f1  f2  f3  f4  f5  date1   date2
0   a   b   d   f   e   2014-09-16 01:57:48 2017-07-13 02:01:03
1   s   d   fe  r   t   2014-09-17 01:57:48 2017-07-23 02:01:03
2   wa  db  td  yf  de  2013-09-26 01:57:48 2017-07-13 02:01:03
3   aws dedr    tgyfe   juir    ttt 2018-09-17 01:57:48 2017-07-23 02:01:03
```

Comment: @Naaraayanan45 did it help mate?

Answer (score 0):

To convert datetime-s you can use the following code:

```
from datetime import datetime
x='2014-09-16T01:57:48.295Z'

x_conv=str(datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'))
```

Then embed it into pandas dataframe by:

```
data_set['d1_conv']=str(datetime.strptime(data_set['d1'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'))
```